# Generating Form Elements in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, design-patterns, architecture

I have a web app that has a form on just about every page. In order to make sure each form renders the same, as to make changes easier, I want to render all of my form controls in c# in a central place so if I need to add a class to the input or change something, I only have to do it once.

At the moment, I am just using a load of static classes like TextInputHelper, CheckboxInputHelper etc that use StringBuilder to build up the HTML and returns a string to my view.

For example, all of my forms controls are of the basic form:

```
<section>
    <label class="label">Label Text</label>
    <label class="input">
        ...Input Element...
    </label>
</section>
```

What I would like to do is improve this situation as I still have a lot of duplication between the different helper classes, particularly for the wrappers to the form elements. My initial thoughts are to have a class called something like BaseFormControl that has a virtual Render method that has the outer wrapper for the control, then create other classes that implement this to do specific things like a TextFormControl that puts

```
<input type="text".....
```

inside the wrapper.

Am I on the right path for this, and/or is there a design pattern that is appropriate for what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my POV what I read is that you over complicating your server side just because of a CSS/HTML standardization that be easily solved from the client side.

If you still want to go for the server side approach the pattern that seems to apply to your approach is the Adapter(Wrapper) pattern meaning that you probably would want to create control wrapper clases to meet your needs for each control that renders a different html from what is offered by ASP.NET built-in controls.

If what you want to do instead is to format a group of controls then a UserControl is way much better approach.

Remember that ASP.NET was build with the spirit of trying to keep layers separated the View from the Code therefore any attempt to generate html from the server side has to be an exception and not a rule.